# Add an id to a <ul> tag in runtime using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="photobooth">
    <div class="blind"></div>
    <canvas ></canvas>
    <div class="warning notSupported"></div>
    <div class="warning noWebcam"></div>
    <ul>
       <li title="hue" class="hue"></li>
       <li title="saturation" class="saturation"></li>
       <li title="brightness" class="brightness"></li>
       <li title="crop" class="crop"></li>
       <li title="take picture" class="trigger"></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

I want `<ul>` tag to have an id during runtime. For example `<ul id="myid"></ul>`. How to do that in javascript?

Comment: if  you have multiple `<ul>` tags you may want to add `.photobooth` to the selector mentioned above.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].id = 'myid'` if you don't want to use an external library

Answer (score 0):

You need someway to uniquely select the correct element first and then add an id to it. For example:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('.photobooth > ul');
ul.id = 'someId';
```

That's it.

Comment: I tried what u said but it says, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null.

Comment: By the way I imported a Jquery plugin in which it generates those code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "ul" ).attr( "id","test" );
```

Check out this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/xqx9bh7m/